# Is QQueue missing from PyQt (5)?

Tags: python, pyqt, queue, pyqt5

I'm stumbling over a strange issue: is it possible that the QQueue class from Qt5 (http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qqueue.html) is not present in PyQt? I couldn't import it and then realized it isn't in this list of PyQt5 classes: http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/

Is this true? If so, is there a reason? and an alternative short of implementing my own class

(Reference: [This commit](https://github.com/wbsoft/frescobaldi/pull/981/commits/cfb4cec254a60f67db46033591e323d27d090a00) on Github and discussion in [comments](https://github.com/wbsoft/frescobaldi/pull/981#commitcomment-22874815))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is obviously not possible for PyQt/PySide to support template classes, since they depend on a feature that is specific to C++.

In general, you should just use the equivalent built-in python type instead (or, where applicable, whatever implementation is currently available in the standard library - e.g. [queue.Queue](https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html#queue-objects) or [collections.deque](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.deque)).

PS:

Regarding `QProcess.errorOccurred` - this signal **is** available in PyQt-5.8.2, and has been since at least PyQt-5.3.2 (which is the oldest version I can check). The `QProcess.error` signal is [obsolete](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess-obsolete.html), and should not be used in new code.

PPS:

PyQt5 is certainly not "still in development" (but [PySide for Qt5](https://wiki.qt.io/PySide2) is).

Comment: Thank you. I think it would have been helpful if the class wouldn't simply be missing from the PyQt docs but somehow been indicated as unavailable.
(PPS: This was not *my* assumption ;-) )